# Promise object not returning a value

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am trying to get the value of `asset`:

```
const asset = getAssetInformation(11002);

function getAssetInformation(id) {
    return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/asset-information",
        params: {assetId: id}
    });
}

console.log(asset);
```

The result is:

```
[object Promise]
```

How do I get the returned value from the request?

Comment: [Using promises - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @zero298 that is irrelevant here

Comment: @user633183 I disagree.  This is an issue with not understanding how to `Promise`, an asynchronous primitive.  That question details how to use `Promise` in detail.

Comment: @zero298 the asker is not trying to alter a variable - Sure, this is a very common mistake when dealing with asynchronous values, but it's not a mistake the asker is making here.

Comment: @user633183 got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `async` and `await` is a practical way -

```js
function axios(query) { // fake axios, for demo
  return new Promise (r =>
    setTimeout(r, 1000, { asset: query.params.assetId })
  )
}

function getAssetInformation(id) {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "/asset-information",
    params: {assetId: id}
  })
}

async function main() { // async
  const asset = await getAssetInformation (11022) // await
  console.log(asset)
}

main()
// 1 second later ...
// { asset: 11022 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use .then function.

```
const asset = getAssetInformation(11002)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Promises return another promise.

The way to unpack and work with a promise is through the .then() function, which will run after the promise returns.

```
const asset = getAssetInformation(11002);

function getAssetInformation(id) {
    return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/asset-information",
        params: {assetId: id}
    });
}
```

Asset here is a promise, you want to use a then on it to get the value.

Instead of..

```
const asset = getAssetInformation(11002);
```

use

```
getAssetInformation(11002)
.then((response) => {
//What you returned will be here, use response.data to get your data out.

} )
.catch((err) => {
//if there is an error returned, put behavior here. 
})
```